# Angular.js 1.x app initialized on window

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm not quite sure on the wording on that title, but either way:
I'm starting to learn Angular.js 1.x for an upcoming project and one of the things I have access to is a working website that uses it to display and sort a list of products. However on the code, where the angular app is initialized, the examples usually do it as

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
```

However on this project I see it initialized as:

```
window.frontEnd = angular.module("FrontEnd", []);
```

I don't quite understand why the app is being initialized on `window.frontend` and if that has any advantage over the usual `var app`

Comment: depends on the entire content of the file.  "var app" will be bound to local scope if issued within the function body. window is global reference to window object. However, if both are called on the top level, then no difference, I think.

Comment: There's likely no difference between the two. `var app` is probably a global and so is `window.frontEnd`